# Spigot 1.17 Player console event

Tags: minecraft

Ok so im making this really dumb plugin because i am new. but i thought this would work and it does not for i dont know why

```
public final class MyFirstPlugin extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        System.out.println("[DeathBan] Plugin Enabled");

        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerDeath(PlayerDeathEvent event){
        String playerName = "Name";
        Player p = Bukkit.getPlayer(playerName);
        Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "ban" + p);
    }

}
```

So what it does is really simple. it see's a player has died. and the console bans them.
It dosnt do anything in console like it should

Answer (score 1):

First remove the `System.out.println` in the onEnable function. You can get the player that died by using `Player p = event.getEntity();` and you should instead ban players by using `Bukkit.getBanList(Type.NAME).addBan(p.getName(), "Ban message", null, "console");` and then kicking the player
It should look like this

```
public void onPlayerDeath(PlayerDeathEvent event){
    Player p = event.getEntity();
    Bukkit.getBanList(Type.NAME).addBan(p.getName(), "Ban message", null, "console");
    p.kickPlayer("Banned");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, again im new to coding but i had this idea for a stream and wanted to do it myself. sadly dont have the java smarts :(